# not able to log in to mysql

Tags: mysql

hi all when I am writing

> mysql -u root

i am getting :

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server
>   through socket
>   '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

what to do next ?I am in ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a number of things could be wrong - mysqld could be down, it could have permissions issues, or there could be an issue with your bind-address or network loopback.

To figure out which of these might be the issue, can you try running:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

and post if you get any errors (depending on your machine, that might also tell you to run:

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

Comment: Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8)
utility, e.g. service mysql restart

Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an
Upstart job, you may also use the restart(8) utility, e.g. restart mysql
mysql start/running, process 3462

Comment: I AM GETTING THE ABOVE ERROR AFTER FOLLOWING YOUR ANSWER

Comment: @yosanu Can you try running sudo service mysql restart and then trying to start mysql again?

Comment: thanks david u are really great...Now its working :..:lol..yeee

Answer (score 1):

ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can’t connect to local MySQL server through socket ‘/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock’

if you are new to installing mysql server you might probably face this error quite often if you type mysql in the shell prompt.

> mysql
>   ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'

To fix:

First start the mysql daemon, then type mysql

> /etc/init.d/mysqld start
>   mysql

Bingo! It worked for me!

To update mysql root password

```
mysql> USE mysql;  
mysql> UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('new-password') WHERE user='root';  
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

To add a new user to mysql

1. First login as root then create a database ‘demo’

> mysql -u root -p
>   Enter password:
>   mysql> create database demo;

After that create a new user named ‘guest’ with password ‘guest’ with all previleges assigned to demo database;

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mytest.* TO 'guest'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'guest' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Then exit mysql and connect through username guest;
That should work!